# Read from stdin and fill buffer until EOF

Tags: c, file-io, io

I need to read from stdin and fill a buffer of _SC_PAGESIZE (from sysconf()) until stdin is at EOF. This program is supposed to be a wc clone, so I would be expecting something like the contents of a regular file to be passed in. If the buffer isn't big enough for stdin, then I have to keep filling it, process it for information, then clear it and continue to fill the buffer again from the file offset in stdin. I'm just having a problem with tracking the EOF of stdin, and I'm getting an infinite loop. Here's what I have:

```
int pSize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
char *buf = calloc(pSize, sizeof(char));
assert(buf);
if (argc < 2) {
        int fd;
        while (!feof(stdin)) {
                fd = read(0, buf, pSize);
                if (fd == -1)
                        err_sys("Error reading from file\n");
                lseek(0, pSize, SEEK_CUR);
                if (fd == -1)
                        err_sys("Error reading from file\n");
                processBuffer(buf);
                buf = calloc(pSize, sizeof(char));
        }
        close(fd);
}
```

I'm assuming the problem has to do with the test condition (while (!feof(stdin)), so I guess what I need is a correct test condition to exit the loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: You write `stdin(pipe, redirection, etc.)` which seems odd, unless you recognize that `etc` includes `regular file`.  There's absolutely nothing magical about stdin.  It's just like any other `FILE *`.  Some might even say it's standard.   But what seems really strange is that although your questions suggests that you expect stdin to be a non-seekable file, you call `lseek` and don't check if it succeeds!

Comment: The loop should be `while (1) { size_t bytes = read(0, buf, pSize); if (0 == bytes) break; <do stuff> };`

Comment: See also [why `while(feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: `lseek(0, pSize, SEEK_CUR);` can fail.  Try `lseek(0, fd, SEEK_CUR);`

Comment: `processBuffer(buf);` should be `processBuffer(buf, fd);` to cope with partial buffers.

Comment: What should happen if the last `read()` before `EOF` occurs and it is partially filled?

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using a low-level `read` instead of opening a `FILE *stream` and using `fgets` (or POSIX `getline`)? Further, you leak memory every time you call:

```
            buf = calloc(pSize, sizeof(char));
```

in your loop because you overwrite the address contained in `buf` losing the reference to the previous block of memory making it impossible to `free`.

Instead, allocate your buffer once, then continually fill the buffer passing the filled buffer to `processBuffer`. You can even use a *ternary operator* to determine whether to open a file or just read from `stdin`, e.g.

```
int pSize = sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE);
char *buf = calloc(pSize, sizeof(char));
assert(buf);

FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
if (!fp) {
    perror ("fopen failed");
    return 1;
}

while (fgets (buf, pSize, fp))
    processBuffer(buf);     /* do not call calloc again -- memory leak */

if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */
```

(**note:** since `fgets` will read a line-at-a-time, you can simply count the number of iterations to obtain your line count -- provided your lines are not longer than `_SC_PAGESIZE`)

If you want to use exact `pSize` chunks, then you can use `fread` instead of `fgets`. The only effect would be to reduce the number of calls to `processBuffer` marginally, but it is completely up to you. The only thing that you would need to do is change the `while (...)` line to:

```
while (fread (buf, (size_t)pSize, 1, fp) == 1)
    processBuffer(buf);     /* do not call calloc again -- memory leak */

if (ferror(fp))     /* you can test ferror to insure loop exited on EOF */
    perror ("fread ended in error");
```

(**note:** like `read`, `fread` does not insure a *nul-terminated* string in `buf`, so insure that `processBuffer` does not pass `buf` to a function expecting a string, or iterate over `buf` expecting to find a *nul-terminating* character at the end.)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Another good point -- especially since we are working with a black-box of `processBuffer`.

Comment: Would it work if I used memset() to put null '/0' in the buffer instead of calloc-ing like you said?

Comment: *since `fgets` will read a line-at-a-time, you can simply count the number of iterations to obtain your line count*  that's not 100% true, if the line is longer as what `pSize`, then `fgets` will not read the whole line. You should count the read input as a line if the newline is present in `buf`.

Comment: Them some long lines -- but you is correct again -- updated/qualified.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the loop like

```
int n;
do {
    n = read(0, buf, pSize);
    // process it
} while(n > 0);
```

Remember EOF is just one exit condition that may not occur before any other error condition occurs. True check for validity to run the loop is a healthy return code from `read`. Also, note that condition `while(n > 0)` is enough or not depends on where you are reading from. In case of `stdin` it may be enough. But for example for sockets the condition can be written like `while(n > 0 || errno == EAGAIN)`

Comment: `n = read(0, buf, pSize);
    // process it` omits the error case of `n == -1`.   Might as well have `if (n <= 0) break; // process it } while (1);`

Comment: isn't that `while(n > 0)` takes care of any -ve and 0 ret code.

Comment: True, the `while(n > 0)` quits the loop due to negative value, yet _after_ the `// process it` code.  I would expect a branch of code immediately after the `n = read(....)` when an error occurs.  Perhaps `while ((n = read(0, buf, pSize)) > 0) { ; // process it }`

Comment: @chux that is indeed correct. Thanks for spotting it.